# Having an issue with the JS form validator. Console in Chrome shows no errors but the validation is not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

This is supposed to handle the form validation for a simple contact form with name, email address, website url, and 10 line comment section for project description, then hand the information as a JSON object to a php file to send to a designated email address.

When I had `action="emailprocessor.php` in the HTML code, the form validation went through the PHP file and not JS, and it sent properly to the designated email address.

Without the action in the html, it's supposed to flow through the JS and then to the PHP. It's not doing that.

Here is my code:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    const contactForm = document.getElementById('contactform');
    contactForm.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);

    //Messages to be put in the message element when there is an error or success...
    // The last element in this array loads the preloader css.
    const feedBackMessage = [

        '<div class="error"><h3>Ooops!</h3><p>The name field is reqired, that\'s how I know who you are. Please fix that and try again!</p></div>',
        '<div class="error"><h3>Ooops!</h3><p>You forgot to give me a valid email address. Please fix that and try again!</p></div>',
        '<div class="error"><h3>Ooops!</h3><p>You forgot to enter your website. Please fix that and try again!</p></div>',
        '<div class="error"><h3>Ooops!</h3><p>Please enter your project description or comment.</p></div>',
        '<div class="success"><h3>Thank you!</h3><p>Your information has been sent, and we will be in touch.</p></div>',
        '<div class="preloader"><div class="loading-dot"></div></div>'

    ];

    // The actual form validation function. Added url regex.    
    function validateForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const nameField = document.getElementById('name');
        const emailField = document.getElementById('email');
        const siteField = document.getElementById('website');
        const commentField = document.getElementById('comment');
        
        const reName = /^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\- ][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/;
        const reEmail = /^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$/;
        const reUrl = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;

        let errors = 0;

        if (!reName.test(nameField.value)) {
            displayMessage(nameField, feedBackMessage[0]);
            errors++;
        }

        else if (!reEmail.test(emailField.value)) {
            displayMessage(emailField, feedBackMessage[1]);
            errors++;
        }

        else if (!reUrl.test(siteField.value)) {
            displayMessage(siteField, feedBackMessage[2]);
            errors++;
        }

        else if (commentField.value == "") {
            displayMessage(commentField, feedBackMessage[3]);
            errors++;
        }

        else if (errors === 0) {
            sendData();
        }
    }

    // This displays error / success messages
    
    function displayMessage(field, message) {
        document.getElementById('message').className = "show-message";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('message').classList.add("fadeOutElement");
            setTimeout(function () {
                if  (field != 'success') {
                    document.getElementById('message').className = "hide-message";
                    document.getElementById(field.id).focus();
                }
                
                else {
                    document.getElementById('message').setAttribute("class", "hide-message");
                    document.getElementById('name').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('email').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('website').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('comment').value = '';
                }
            }, 2000);
        }, 2000);
        //puts messages in the DOM??
    }

    function sendData() {
        document.getElementById('message').className = "show-message";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = feedBackMessage[5];
        setTimeout(async () => {
                const formdata = new FormData(contactForm);
                const fetchPromise = await fetch('emailprocessor.php', { method: 'POST', body: formdata });
                const data = await fetchPromise.json();
                console.log(data.result);
                if (data.result == "success") {
                    displayMessage('success', feedBackMessage[4]);
                }
            }, 2000);
    }   
        //actually sends the data asynchronously or so it claims
});
```

Comment: I just tested you code and it is working, can you insure that the sendData function is not being called at all ?

Comment: I've been going through it line by line and there seems to be an issue with the URL regex.